# Using workbench to connect to SQL server on management studio

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, management-studio-express

I have been trying to connect to the server on Microsoft SQL Management Studio using Workbench via an IP.

But I cannot seem to connect whatsoever, is workbench even supported with Database engine servers.

I am connecting with the root username, could that be the problem too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to MySQL Workbench and SQL Server, MySQL is a visualization tools for MySQL Server and databases. You cannot access other servers with it. **SSMS or SQL Server Management studio is the visualization tool for SQL Server databases**. These both databases use almost similar syntax and structure but are totally different entities in terms of Parent Company and access.

In Layman's terms, when you try to enter an IP in Workbench, it tries to find and access a MySQL Server but doesn't find it and hence does not connect. It is not a SSH Client which connects to any server specified.

There is one way to connect SQL Server from MySQL Workbench and that is database miration.

[Find More Information Here:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard-connection.html)

I recommend SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server Access and visualization.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks - how would I then connect to a server through python. Would it be the same process or a different module I'd have to install?

Comment: @Govind75 there are separate drivers / connectors for each database product in python.

Comment: @Govind75 Workbench and SSMS are tools for viewing tables on server at individual level. When you are developing you will need to connect it using drivers/Connectors as mentioned by

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to SQL Server using Python, consider PyODBC (preferred) or pymssql as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)